# Dashed line doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, csv, d3.js

I have a list of radio buttons indicating a country.
I want that when user clicks on a radio button, the right line chart are loaded.
To do so I have 4 csv files with data for each country.

The csv files are like this:

```
year,death,value
2012,Tuberculosis,NA
2011,Tuberculosis,NA
2010,Tuberculosis,301
2009,Tuberculosis,344
2008,Tuberculosis,333
2007,Tuberculosis,329
2006,Tuberculosis,350
2005,Tuberculosis,NA
2004,Tuberculosis,NA
2003,Tuberculosis,396
2002,Tuberculosis,413
2001,Tuberculosis,415
2000,Tuberculosis,460
1999,Tuberculosis,517
1998,Tuberculosis,558
1997,Tuberculosis,597
1996,Tuberculosis,609
1995,Tuberculosis,647
2012,Tetanus,NA
2011,Tetanus,NA
2010,Tetanus,17
2009,Tetanus,27
2008,Tetanus,18
...
```

[**HERE**](https://plnkr.co/edit/2IzQnbrE5yLg3IkU5joQ?p=preview) is my code.
I don't know why Plunker create the error "**Bad request**".

Anyway, this is my result: if the user clicks on Italy, then the browser loads Italy.csv file and creates the chart, if the user clicks on Hungary, then browser loads Hungary.csv file and creates the chart and so on.

The problem is that in my csv files, there are some "holes" on data.
For example, I haven't any data about number of deaths in Italy between 2003 and 2006 so I want to show a dashed line instead of a solid line.
In my chart I'm not able to do that.
In particular, I wrote code to do that but it doesn't work.
Note that the missing data will change according to the countries. For some countries I have all the data and not for other countries.

Also, if the user clicks on the circle (the legend) of the corresponding series disappears, the circle should turn white and the axes change to fit the current data.
This doesn't work and I don't understand why.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the console doesn't show any errors.

In this similar example, it works: [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tuROdVexy61V16NrgMUa?p=preview)

---

I badly explained myself. With "missing data" I mean NA values.

[NEW PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/AHGOzHpuL2YXgcPdIlIV?p=preview)

---

I understand that the chart of Belgium is right. 
I tried to understand why the Denmark chart is that but sorry, I don't understand when you say "*Code generate multiples paths for every abailable data and just ONE path for all NA data. Instead it must generate a segments for every gap on data.*".

The code is organized in this way:

```
// some code...

/************************************************************************** 
 *** GET SELECTED COUNTRY AND DRAW FIRST CHART ****************************
 **************************************************************************/
var l_selectedCountry = document.querySelector('input[name="l_country"]:checked').value;
l_createLineChart(l_selectedCountry);
var l_updateradio = function() {
    l_selectedCountry = $('input[name=l_country]:checked', '#l_countries').val(); 
    l_createLineChart(l_selectedCountry);
}
$("#l_countries").on("change", l_updateradio);

/************************************************************************** 
 *** DRAW THE RIGHT CHART BASED ON SELECTED COUNTRY  **********************
 **************************************************************************/
function l_createLineChart(l_selectedCountry) {
  // remove last chart
  d3.select("#l_chartcontainer")
    .html("");

  // adds the svg canvas
  var svg = d3.select("#l_chartcontainer") 
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", l_width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", l_height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var l_file = "./data/line_data/" + l_selectedCountry + ".csv";

  /************************************************************************** 
  *** GET RIGHT DATA ********************************************************
  **************************************************************************/
  d3.csv(l_file, function(l_error, l_data) { 

    l_data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.year = parseDate(d.year);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

    // code about axis...

    /************************************************************************** 
    *** GET ALL LINE DATA (solid & dashed) ************************************
    **************************************************************************/
    var l_dataNest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { 
            return d.death; 
        })
        .entries(l_data);
    console.log("l_dataNest");
    console.log(l_dataNest);    

    // code about labels...

    /************************************************************************** 
    *** GET DASHED LINE DATA **************************************************
    **************************************************************************/
    var l_dashedData = l_getDashed(l_dataNest); // dashed line (extreme point) for each disease
    console.log("l_dashedData");
    console.log(l_dashedData);

    // other code...

    /************************************************************************** 
    *** DRAW SOLID LINE *******************************************************
    **************************************************************************/
    svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'l_line-container')
      .selectAll('.normal-line-paths')
      .data(l_dataNest) // set our data
      .enter() // enter the data and start appending elements
      .append('path')
      .call(l_path); // calling our path function for later use when appending lines

    /************************************************************************** 
    *** DRAW DASHED LINE ******************************************************
    **************************************************************************/
    svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'dashed-line-container')
      .selectAll('.dashed-line-paths')
      .data(l_dashedData)
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .call(l_dashedPath);

    // other code...
  });
}

// code about event...

function l_path(myPath) {
  myPath.style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return l_color[d.key];
    })
    .attr('class', function(d) {
        return 'normal-line-paths path-' + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        return valueline(d.values);
    })
    .style("opacity", 0.5)
    .on("mouseover", l_onMouseOverLine)
    .on("mouseout", l_onMouseOutLine);
}

function l_dashedPath(myPath) {
  myPath.style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return l_color[d.key];
    })
    .style("stroke-width", 5)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", '4')
    .attr('class', function(d) {
        return 'dashed-line-paths path-' + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        return valueline(d.values);
    })
    .style("opacity", 0.5)
    .on("mouseover", l_onMouseOverLine)
    .on("mouseout", l_onMouseOutLine);
}

/**
 * Function to return the data points that will create the dashed lines.
 */
function l_getDashed(data) {
  return data.map(function(collection, index) {
    var l_startNaN = false;
    var l_dashed = {
     key: collection.key, // disease
     values: [] //array of death, death and year
    };
    collection.values.forEach(function(dataPoint, index) {
      var l_value = dataPoint.value;
      var values = collection.values;           
      if($.isNumeric(l_value) && l_startNaN) {
        l_startNaN = false;
       l_dashed.values.push(values[index]);
      } 
      else {
       if(($.isNumeric(l_value) && l_startNaN) || (!$.isNumeric(l_value) && !l_startNaN)) {
          l_startNaN = true;
          l_dashed.values.push(values[index-1]);
        }
      }
    })
    if((l_dashed.values.length % 2)) {
      l_dashed.values.pop();
    }
    return l_dashed;
  });
}
```

If I comment this piece of code:

```
// apend a group element which will contain our dashed lines
/*svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'dashed-line-container')
    .selectAll('.dashed-line-paths')
    .data(l_dashedData)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .call(l_dashedPath);*/
```

I get:

[image]

and if I comment:

```
// apend a group element which will contain our lines
/*svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'l_line-container')
    .selectAll('.normal-line-paths')
    .data(l_dataNest) // set our data
    .enter() // enter the data and start appending elements
    .append('path')
    .call(l_path); */
```

I get:

[image]

So there must be a problem in `l_dashedPath(myPath)` method. 
But if I print `d`, I get the four ends of the two portions dashed (Tuberculosis): 23, 32, 15, 16 that are correct.

```
.attr("d", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    return valueline(d.values);
})
```

Also the `l_getDashed(data)` method seems correct to me.

Comment: Of sure, but values are NA. And I create function `dashedPath` for these cases..

Comment: I've update your plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/2IzQnbrE5yLg3IkU5joQ?p=preview

Comment: Inside Plunker you can't have spaces on filename. Rename it 'United Kingdom.csv' to something with underscore (_) or so. "United_Kingdom.csv"

Comment: @Klaujesi Oh thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this a graph for disease? If so, you need something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/enLiKxADx5ZFpVMdakSC?p=preview or this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090

Comment: In fact, the correct type is this: https://plnkr.co/edit/0ed9388IJE54lXpYFjvA?p=preview

Comment: @Klaujesi I would like to use the chart I've done that already works (https://plnkr.co/edit/tuROdVexy61V16NrgMUa?p=preview). I would like to make it work for every country..

Comment: You're passing wrong values to function l_dashedpath. It generate this:  d="M329.42502818489294,145.64381574174828Z". Just a point, not a line

Answer (score 0):

Inside Plunker you can't have **spaces** on filename. Rename it `'United Kingdom.csv'` to something with underscore (_) or so. `"United_Kingdom.csv"`

Your function l_getdashed, don't take the next point for every dashed segment. At the end you just get a point, not a segment.

I'ver re-refactory your function:

```
function l_getDashed(data) {
    return data.map(function(collection, index) {
        var l_startNaN = false;
        var l_dashed = {
            key: collection.key,
            values: []
        };
        collection.values.forEach(function(dataPoint, index) {
            var l_value = dataPoint.value;
            var values = collection.values;         

            if ($.isNumeric(l_value) && l_startNaN) {
                l_startNaN = false;
                l_dashed.values.push(values[index]);
            } else if ( !$.isNumeric(l_value) !== l_startNaN) {
                l_startNaN = true
                l_dashed.values.push(values[index-1]);
            }
        })
        if (l_dashed.values.length % 2) { l_dashed.values.pop() }
        return l_dashed;
    });
}
```

[Here the update working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lpa6vEjeo9iVOxYHK7sI)

**DENMARK**

Your code has concept errors. Thats why you see 'Denmark' like that.

Graphically:

[image]

Code generate multiples paths for every abailable data and just ONE path for all NA data. Instead it must generate a segments for every gap on data.-

**BELGIUM**

Belguim is a different history. The graph is ok, your data has isolated points  (red dots) and can not be dismiss.

[image]

You can not draw a dashed-line from 1997-2009 (black arrow) because you'll discarding data.

Comment: Thanks, I added some values to test your solution and noticed that there are some problems: (1) if you look at Poland, the dashed line does not appear (2) if you look at Denmark, the dashed line is not correct, it has a strange walk (3 ) now look at Belgium. I don't understand the trend of the dashed line. The dashed line should simply join the two extremes in which I have data, it shouldn't have its own trend..

This is the updated code so you understand better

Comment: Sorry, I can't see where the new Plunker is.

Comment: Ops :-) you are right, I edited my main message with a new link.

Comment: Code updated. Try to refactoy your code to make it simple.

Comment: I modified the Plunker, now the user can choose which series display and graph fits the data. In what sense refactoring? I added a bit of prints and it seems that the data of Denmark and Belgium are correct, yet the graph continues to be wrong. I don't know how I could simplify the code, the thing is now "running", it takes the two known ends. Of course it is not perfect (because if the NA data are at the beginning or at the end, then the dashed line can not be built). In any case, I can't understand why for Belgium and Denmark the graph is in this way.

Comment: Sorry again. I modified the main message.

Comment: No. What you see is: [star-point:23, intermiediate-value:32, intermiediate-value:15, end-point:16]. What you need is: [start-point:23, end-point:32][start-point:16. end-point:16]

Comment: ah. Ok then the problem is in the `l_getDashed(data)` method. Thank you, I try to solve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116393/discussion-between-klaujesi-and-buster).